# What is the constitutional status of military bases?

Tags: united-states, law, constitution, government

Does the United States Constitution have any amendments related to foreign bases? Technically foreign bases aren't U.S. territory, but they must have some laws.

Comment: Do you really only want to ask about the constitutional status or about the legal status in general?

Comment: @SvenClement Both, but i noticed that many questions in one is not well seen.

Comment: Actually US bases on foreign soil are US territory. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_territory

Comment: @Popo no, that is incorrect.  Even the article you link to says "Despite exercise of extraterritorial jurisdiction, these overseas locations remain under the sovereignty of the host countries."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the base is on a foreign territory, the rules are a union of:

- UCMJ - United States Uniform Code of Military Justice (applicable to uniformed personnel)
- Whatever local laws may be applicable based on United States' treaties/agreements with the placement nation

  - officially signed treaties are considered a law on par with Constitution ([src](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supremacy_Clause))
  - those countries where we have bases not covered by an official treaty, the jurisdictional rules are defined by something called **[status of forces agreements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Status_of_forces_agreement)**

For those interested in a government's official explanation of the nitty gritty of how this works, you can read through [Army Pamphlet 360-544: YOU AND THE LAW OVERSEAS](http://www.apd.army.mil/jw2/xmldemo/p360_544/main.asp) from 1989.